# Getting coordinates of open windows in java on a mac

Tags: java, macos, swing

I need to be able to find the coordinates of windows open in a computer even if they are not created by my application or by another java application.  I am at a loss for any way of doing this besides screen-shotting the whole screen and then trying to have the app trace the outlines of each window, which seems horribly innefficient and probably not very effective (what if the windows were overlapping)?

Any help is hugely appreciated:  I've spent all day trying to figure it out!

**Note:** I need to do this on a mac, and I don't need to be able to port it to windows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get information from the operating system, and there are various ways to do that with Java, but none use only *core* Java. I suggest trying out [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to allow you to call OS functions directly without all the fuss involved with using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: I looked at it and I came across the quartz windows service in Carbon, which looks like it would do the trick, but I had two problems.  It looks like the function I wanted to use (CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo) returns an array of a type other than the basic ones, and I don't know how I would handle it.  Secondly, I could not figure out how to call it in the first place, as I could not figure out which header it was declared in or where it was located.  Obviously this is as a result of my being completely unskilled with JNA, but I would really appreciate assistance if you don't mind.

Comment: @ThomasPaltz - I don't think someone is going to code you up an example ... if that is what you are asking.  Give it a go yourself, and ask a new question if you have concrete problems.